# Converting sequential code into parallel

Tags: java, python, mapreduce, apache-spark

I'm trying to understand MapReduce with Spark.
When doing some simple exercises, I have no problems, doing it the sequential way, but when it comes to parallelise my code, I experience difficulties.

Consider the following example:

```
var = "Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts."
k = 10;

for x in range(0, len(var)):
    print(var[0+x:k+x])
```

It splits a text into shingles of 10 characters ([w-shingling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling)).
What would be the right way to "convert" it into parallel code using Spark?

How to code a `for loop`? Does Spark offer loops anyway?

I just need to understand the whole concept.

PS: I've already read the documentation, I know what RDDs are etc. I just don't know, how to "convert" sequential code into parallel.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have read already, Spark has a rich functional API. The RDD operations are classified into `transformations` and `actions`, where `transformations` could be seen as functions that take an RDD and produce an RDD: `f(RDD) => RDD` and actions as functions that take an RDD and produce some result (`Array[T]` in case of `collect` or `Unit` in case of `foreach`).

The general idea on how to port a certain algorithm to Spark is to find a way to express said algorithm using the  functional paradigm supported by Spark, by combining transformations and actions to achieve the desired outcome.

Algorithms that depend on a sequence, like the w-shingling above, present a challenge to be parallelized as there's an implicit dependency in the order of the elements that's sometimes difficult to express is such a way that could be operated in different partitions.

In this case, I used indexing as a way to preserve the sequence while making possible to express the algorithm in terms of transformations:

```
def kShingle(rdd:RDD[Char], n:Int): RDD[Seq[Char]] = {
    def loop(base: RDD[(Long, Seq[Char])], cumm: RDD[(Long, Seq[Char])], i: Int): RDD[Seq[Char]] = {
       if (i<=1) cumm.map(_._2) else {
        val segment =  base.map{case (idx, seq) => (idx-1, seq)}
        loop(segment, cumm.join(segment).map{case (k,(v1,v2)) => (k,v1 ++ v2)}, i-1)
        }
    }
    val seqRdd = rdd.map(char => Seq(char))
    val indexed = seqRdd.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)

    loop(indexed, indexed, n)
}
```

Spark-shell Example:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize("Floppy Disk")
scala> kShingle(rdd,3).collect
res23: Array[Seq[Char]] = Array(List(F, l, o), List(i, s, k), List(l, o, p), List(o, p, p), List(p, p, y), List(p, y,  ), List(y,  , D), List( , D, i), List(D, i, s))
```